# YA novel with child, talking cat, and airships, bearded man, battle with long-barreled rifles

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel

Seeking a story I read in the early 1980s, possibly by a British author. It involves a child travelling by airship with a talking siamese (?) cat and meeting or travelling with a bearded man. I think there was a battle with long-barrelled rifles.

Would love to read it again!

Comment: Probably not but shares some similarities with Phillip Pullman's Northern Lights.

Answer (score 3):

As per Bellerphon's comment, Phillip Pullman's *[The Golden Compass](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northern_Lights_(novel))* (aka *Northern Lights*) has a child protagonist with a talking dæmon that is sometimes a cat, an airship (a balloon owned by Texan Lee Soresby), and Lee's rifle. However, it was released in 1995.